# Exception in Tkinter Callback in python which inturn gives AttributeError

Tags: python, image, tkinter, python-imaging-library

```
def find_face(img,img_size=(160,160)):

    img = cv2.imread(img)
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    img = np.asarray(img) # converting our image obj to numpy array
    faces = detector.detect_faces(img)
    if faces:
        x,y,w,h = faces[0]['box']
        x,y=abs(x),abs(y)
        face = img[y:y+h,x:x+w]
        face = Image.fromarray(face) # converting it to image object to resize it
        face = face.resize(img_size) # resizing it
        face = np.asarray(face)      # converting it back to array
        return face
    return None

def load_dataset(path):

    X = []
    y = []
    for people in os.listdir(path):
        for people_images in os.listdir(path+people):
            face = find_face(path+people+'/'+people_images)
            if face is None:
                continue
            emb = embed(face)
            X.append(emb)
            y.append(people)
        print('Loaded {} images of {}'.format(
            len(os.listdir(path+'/'+people)), people))
    return np.asarray(X), np.asarray(y)
def addDetails():

    if USERNAME.get() == '' or NAME.get() == '' or PASSWORD.get() == '':
        lbl_err = Label(error, text="Please enter all the details !", fg="red")
        lbl_err.pack()
    else:
        global con, c
        con = sql.connect('LogInDataBase.db')
        c = con.cursor()
        params = (USERNAME.get(), PASSWORD.get())
        c.execute(f"""INSERT INTO `Student` (username , password) 
            VALUES (? , ?)
            """, params)
        con.commit()
        c.close()
        con.close()
        nameStr = NAME.get() + "-" + ROLL.get()
        if nameStr in os.listdir('faces/train'):
            lbl_err = Label(error, text="User already exist in faces !", fg="red")
            lbl_err.pack()
            print('User already exist in faces')
        else:
            root.quit()
            os.makedirs('faces/train/'+nameStr)
            os.makedirs('faces/val/'+nameStr)
            cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
            i = 0
            print()
            for i in range(5):
                print(f'Capturing starts in {5-i} seconds...')
                time.sleep(1)
            print('Taking photos...')
            while i <= 200:
                ret, frame = cap.read()
                cv2.imshow('taking your pictures', frame)
                if i % 5 == 0 and i <= 150 and i != 0:
                    cv2.imwrite('faces/train/'+nameStr+'/'+str(i)+'.png', frame)
                elif i % 5 == 0 and i > 150:
                    cv2.imwrite('faces/val/'+nameStr+'/'+str(i)+'.png', frame)
                i += 1
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            cap.release()
            print('Successfully taken your photos...')
            # ============================= Loading Dataset ====================================
            print('Loading train data...')
            X_train, y_train = load_dataset('faces/train/')

            print()

            print('Loading test data...')
            X_test, y_test = load_dataset('faces/val/')

            # l2 normalizing the data
            l2_normalizer = Normalizer('l2')

            X_train = l2_normalizer.transform(X_train)
            X_test = l2_normalizer.transform(X_test)

            # label encoding the y data
            label_enc = LabelEncoder()
            y_train = label_enc.fit_transform(y_train)
            y_test = label_enc.transform(y_test)

            ############ Training SVC (Support Vector Classifier) for predicting faces ########
            # svc = SVC(kernel='linear',probability=True)
            # svc.fit(X_train,y_train)

            rfc = RandomForestClassifier()
            rfc.fit(X_train, y_train)

            joblib.dump(rfc, 'models/face_prediction_model.sav')
            print()

            print('Random Forest Model saved successfully!!')

            text_to_speech("New user added SUCCESSfully!!!")
```

**And I am reciving this Error :**

```
Exception in Tkinter callback

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)

  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_8172\1025443354.py", line 188, in addDetails

    X_train, y_train = load_dataset('faces/train/')

  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_8172\1025443354.py", line 75, in load_dataset

    face = find_face(path+people+'/'+people_images)

  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_8172\1025443354.py", line 48, in find_face

    face = Image.fromarray(face) # converting it to image object to resize it
AttributeError: type object 'Image' has no attribute 'fromarray'
```

Comment: have you `from PIL import Image`

Comment: [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45687511/type-object-image-has-no-attribute-fromarray)